# Mod function fails in python for large numbers

Tags: python-2.7, math

This python code

```
for x in range(20, 50):
    print(x,math.factorial(x),math.pow(2,x), math.factorial(x) % math.pow(2,x)  )
```

calculates fine up  to x=22 but the mod when x>22 is always 0.

Wolframalpha says the results for x>22 are nonzero.
For example, when [x=23](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=25852016738884976640000%20mod%208388608) we get 6815744.

I guess this problem results from how python actually calculates the mod function but was wondering if anyone actually knew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running into floating point limitations; `math.pow()` returns a floating point number, so both operands are coerced to floats. For `x = 23`, `math.factorial(x)` returns an integer larger than what a float can model:

```
>>> math.factorial(23)
25852016738884976640000
>>> float(math.factorial(23))
2.585201673888498e+22
```

The right-hand-side operator is a much smaller floating point number (only 7 digits), it is that difference in exponents that causes the modulus operator error out.

Use `**` to stick to integers:

```
for x in range(20, 50):
    print(x, math.factorial(x), 2 ** x, math.factorial(x) % (2 ** x))
```

Integer operations are only limited to how much memory is available, and for `x = 23` the correct value is calculated, continuing to work correctly all the way to `x = 49`:

```
>>> x = 23
>>> print(x, math.factorial(x), 2 ** x, math.factorial(x) % (2 ** x))
23 25852016738884976640000 8388608 6815744
>>> x = 49
>>> print(x, math.factorial(x), 2 ** x, math.factorial(x) % (2 ** x))
49 608281864034267560872252163321295376887552831379210240000000000 562949953421312 492581209243648
```

Note that for even for smaller floating point modulus calculations, you really should be using the [`math.fmod()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.fmod), for reasons explained in the documentation. It too fails for this case however, again because you are reaching beyond the limits of floating point math:

```
>>> print(x, math.factorial(x), math.pow(2, x), math.fmod(math.factorial(x), math.pow(2, x)))
23 25852016738884976640000 8388608.0 0.0
```

Comment: thank you for the solution although I am confused by your statement "The right-hand-side operator is a much smaller floating point number (only 9 digits)"  Which 9 digits?

Comment: @aquagremlin: `8388608.0`, which is 7. Oops.

Comment: also this code gives an interesting plot without errors     `%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.misc
x = np.linspace(0, 5, 70)
plt.plot(scipy.misc.factorial(x) % np.power(2,x))
plt.show()`

Comment: numpy should error out and in fact it does sooner than math.pow so why does that plot work?

Comment: @aquagremlin: `np.power()` returns an integer for integer inputs, and [`scipy.misc.factorial()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.factorial.html) returns an integer by default. Also, `numpy` arrays overload the `%` operator to apply to individual elements, so they can implement it differently from core Python if they so wish.

Comment: @aquagremlin: Note that Martijn's plot only goes from `x=0` to `x=5`, and doesn't actually hit any integers *except* `0.0` and `5.0`. The `%` operation in this case is doing just the same that Python's would. BTW, it's not true that `scipy.misc.factorial` returns an integer by default: it returns a float, unless you pass `exact=True`. @Martijn: I don't understand why you're talking about integers here.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: hrm, I may have misread the documentation: *If exact is 0, then floating point precision is used, otherwise exact long integer is computed.* Since the default is `exact=False` and not `0`, an exact long integer is returned. But if they take `False` as `0` then you'll get a float, yes.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: but you are entirely correct; that plot never approaches values over 22.

Comment: Ah yes, that looks like a (possibly historical) doc bug: it should really say "if exact is false" rather than "if exact is 0".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You are correct for large numbers modulus gives wrong numbers especially with factorial numbers.

for example :

```
import math

def comb(n,r):
    res= math.factorial(n)/(math.factorial(n-r)*math.factorial(r))
    return(float(res))
    
sum1=0
num=888

for r in range(0,num+1):
    sum1 +=comb(num,r)
    

    
print(sum1 % 1000000)
```

gives wrong answer 252480 but the correct answer is 789056 .